# Why I can't get a value of textarea from tinymce editor using FormData in Jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using **Jquery plugin** with **Tinymce editor** to add some post data to Database using Codeigniter.

My Issue I can't get all the value from **textarea** which i used **Tinymce Editor** but another field is working very well.

Here is my **Tinymce editor**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            base_url: false,
            external_filemanager_path: "/filemanager/",
            filemanager_title: "Responsive Filemanager",
            external_plugins: {"filemanager": "<?PHP echo base_url('../filemanager/plugin.min.js') ?>"},
            relative_urls: false,
            plugins: [Full uption ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify ",

        });
    });
</script>
```

And This is my **Jquery Plugin**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#do_upload").on('click', function () {
            if ($("#ch_title").val() === '') {
                alert("You have to input all Chineses language field");
                $("#ch_title").addClass('error');
            }
            if ($("#kh_title").val() === '') {
                alert("You have to input all Khmer language field");
                $("#kh_title").addClass('error');
            }
        });
        $("#eng_form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }).validate({
//             ignore: "",
            rules: {
                eng_title: {
                    required: true
                },
                eng_dd: {
                    required: true
                },
                kh_dd: {
                    required: true
                },
                eng_up_img: {
                    required: true
                }, 
            },
            submitHandler: function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?PHP echo base_url('image/rupload'); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: new FormData($('#eng_form')[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        $("#teset").modal('show');
                        $('<img style="width:60px; height:auto;" src="<?PHP echo base_url('assets/admin/img/ajax-loader-2.gif'); ?>"/>').appendTo("#loading_img");
                    }, complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == 'success') {
                            $("#loading_img").html('');
                            $("#teset").modal('hide');
                            $("#img_modal").modal('hide');
                            $($('#img_upload')).closest($('form')).find("input[type=text], textarea").val(" ");
                            window.location.href = '<?PHP echo base_url('slide/right'); ?>';
                        }
                    }, success: function (data) {

                        var size = data.img_pro.upload.file_size;
                        if (size >= 2048) {
                            alert("Your images size can't more than 2MB" + "Your size:" + size);
                        } else if (data.res === false) {
                            alert("Your images is not correct");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

The result I can't get all the textarea value if I using **Tinymce editor** for array variable **DD** and **description**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that you need to update the `<textarea>` with the contents of the editor before you capture the form's data. I am guessing, and so assume you are grabbing the field values when you create the `FormData` object.

If that is true, then somewhere in the `FormData` constructor move the tinymce editor contents to the `<textarea>` by calling tinymce.Editor.save(). For instance, if your activeEditor instance is referenced in a var named `editor` then `editor.save()` will update the associated `<textarea>` element .

After that you can grab the value of the field using the JQuery .val() function, ie. `someVar = $(#fieldName).val();` Obviously, you need to provide the appropriate names in place of `someVar` and `#fieldName`.